# Coffeescript ajax success call to external function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, coffeescript

I have a list of pending invitations being displayed. When the user accepts one, I want to hide that invitation and show the next invitation, if available.

With this Coffeescript code, the showNextInvitation() throw a "Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function":

```
$('#invitations').on 'click', '.accept-invite-btn', () ->
   $(this).parents('form').ajaxSubmit(
       success: =>
           $(this).parents('.invitation').fadeOut()  
           showNextInvitation() 
   )
   return false
```

With this code, the function works fine, but the targeted invitation doesn't fade:

```
_this = this
$('#invitations').on 'click', '.accept-invite-btn', () ->
   $(this).parents('form').ajaxSubmit(
       success: ->
           $(this).parents('.invitation').fadeOut()  
           _this.showNextInvitation() 
   )
   return false
```

It's clearly a function binding problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to keep the fat arrow for `success:` along with storing `_this`.

```
_this = this
$('#invitations').on 'click', '.accept-invite-btn', () ->
    $(this).parents('form').ajaxSubmit(
        success: =>
            $(this).parents('.invitation').fadeOut()
            _this.showNextInvitation()
    )
    return false
```

With the 2 functions included in your snippets, there are 3 different `this` values involved:

```
# 1) `this` is an object with a `showNextInvitation` method

$('#invitations').on 'click', '.accept-invite-btn', () ->
    # 2) `this` is the `.accept-invite-btn` element that captured the event

    $(this).parents('form').ajaxSubmit(
        success: ->
            # 3) `this` is the object managing the Ajax request, likely a jqXHR

    )
```

Though you've saved #1 by defining `_this`, which allows for calling its method.

```
_this = this

# ...

    _this.showNextInvitation()
```

The 2nd snippet is expecting #3 to be the same as #2, which the fat arrow will do.

---

Alternatively, you could also save #2 to its own variable, perhaps as `$element`, and use thin arrows throughout:

```
_this = this
$('#invitations').on 'click', '.accept-invite-btn', () ->
    $element = $(this)

    $element.parents('form').ajaxSubmit(
        success: ->
            $element.parents('.invitation').fadeOut()
            _this.showNextInvitation()
    )
    return false
```

Comment: Thank you so much! That was exactly the in depth answer I was hoping for - I now understand "why" and will be better able to code in the future.  Oddly, the first solution you presented didn't work - I believe it should, I must have a bug somewhere else. The second is working fine though, so in the interest of time, I'm using that. Thanks again.